# Display Batch file output message in local machine

Tags: batch-file, psexec

I am using psexec tool to run a batch file in remote machine. Everything is good except that I am unable to see any batch output messages that we usually see in cmd window. I want these msgs on my local machine psexec shell window. Is there anyway to do that?

I am using the command as:

`psexec -u admin -p tool@321 \\10.189.21.19 -s -d cmd.exe /c "C:\TEMP\output\batch_script.bat"`

Comment: Have you tried `cmd.exe /K` rather than `cmd.exe /C`?

Comment: No.  Actually I am unaware of /c or /k parameters. maybe i ll try that

Comment: I tried replacing cmd.exe /K but not getting any messages with this one either.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating an admin share and outputting the data there?

`psexec -u admin -p tool@321 \10.189.21.19 -s -d cmd.exe /c "C:\TEMP\output\batch_script.bat >\\server\logs$\10.189.21.19.txt"`

Comment: With this line its just outputting the lines from batch into log. I am talking about the CMD execution messages or response messages. I hope you understand.